# Is there such thing as a non-turbulent wake?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, aerodynamics, turbulence

We learnt in our fluids course that boundary layer separation can occur even for laminar non-turbulent flow (for high viscosity fluid).

In this case, shown as ‘steady separation’ in the diagram below. Is the wake caused by the separated boundary layer actually non-turbulent?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, laminar wakes exist. There are beautiful examples in [An Album of Fluid Motion](http://courses.washington.edu/me431/handouts/Album-Fluid-Motion-Van-Dyke.pdf). The plates of laminar wakes behind cylinders are 40-46. Plate 42, of flow past a cylinder with Re=26, is below. You'll see it looks very similar to the diagram in your question.

[image]

You might also be interested in plates 11-14, where the Reynolds numbers are even lower, Re<0.1. With such low Re, even the flow around a square and a plate perpendicular to the flow is laminar.